# Caching css files in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, cache, css, full-page-cache, .htaccess

Because of the Black Friday, I've added some products as an offer. They can be shown on the main page with a block I had initially hidden with some CSS on my `styles.css` file.
This morning, I removed the `display:none` I had in my `styles.css`. Apart from this, I cleaned server's cache, flushed css/js cache and changed my .htaccess css catch time from 1 week to 1 second.
After doing all this stuff I couldn't still see that block if I didn't clean the cache from my browser.
Isn't there a way to avoid people cleaning their cache's browser and see my css as it is?
By the way, I have installed FPC module, my css files are merged and I have gzip caching on .htaccess, just in case it's related to any of these.

Comment: A temporary fix might be to change the name of your css file, this way browsers will be forced to download the file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lot you can do if someone's browser has decided it wants to cache the css.
What you can do is version your css so if you were to update styles.css you update the name as well for example it would be styles-201.css 
This can be hard to implement (as you need to update anywhere that's calling the file to use the versioned one) but there's tools that do it for you.

Pagespeed (an apache mod and has a nginx version as well) can do this all for you. It can autoversion the css files and it update the html it serves end uses with to use the versioned css, so that if you update the css it make a new version and cu

Comment: It's a good idea, I just need to add the day at the end of the file if I've done  a big update on my main css files (styles.css and responsive.css). There should be something in magento which does that but well, it's something. Thank you